# How can I add a Widget between items in a list?

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, arraylist, widget

### Problem:

> Hi everyone! I have this "*problem*" that I want to add a `Widget` between the elements but I can't... *idk* why, here's an example of my `List` type `ChatMessage`:

```
List<ChatMessage> messages = [
 ChatMessage(content: 'Hi!', type: 'sent', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 7)),
 ChatMessage(content: 'Hello!', type: 'received', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 8)),
 ChatMessage(content: 'How are you?', type: 'received', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 8)),
 ChatMessage(content: 'Im good', type: 'sent', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 9)),
];
```

### Expected:

> The result that I want it's similar in the below block (*Separated by **`DateTime`** dynamically, basically add this "`Widget`" between them automatically just with the `DateTime` condition*)

```
List<ChatMessage> messages = [
 ChatMessage(content: 'Hi!', type: 'sent', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 7)), // Day 7
 // Some Widget...
 ChatMessage(content: 'Hello!', type: 'received', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 8)), // Day 8
 ChatMessage(content: 'How are you?', type: 'received', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 8)), // Day 8
 // Some Widget...
 ChatMessage(content: 'Im good', type: 'sent', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 9)), // Day 9
];
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement the badge `Date xx/yy/zz` above the first message of the day?

Comment: Anyway you need first to group your data (by date?). Then you can render it as a "flat" list

Comment: It seems like what you want is to use a generic `List` in your `ListView` instead of having just your `List<ChatMessage>`. Or even just a list of widgets. This way you could just add items to the list, regardless of their content, before displaying them on the `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Changes to the type of List specified in arrow brackets <>

From this:

```
List<ChatMessage> messages = [
 ChatMessage(content: 'Hi!', type: 'sent', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 7)),
 ChatMessage(content: 'Hello!', type: 'received', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 8)),
 ChatMessage(content: 'How are you?', type: 'received', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 8)),
 ChatMessage(content: 'Im good', type: 'sent', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 9)),
];
```

To this:

```
List<Widget> messages = [
 ChatMessage(content: 'Hi!', type: 'sent', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 7)), // Day 7
 // Some Widget...
 ChatMessage(content: 'Hello!', type: 'received', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 8)), // Day 8
 ChatMessage(content: 'How are you?', type: 'received', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 8)), // Day 8
 // Some Widget...
 ChatMessage(content: 'Im good', type: 'sent', date: DateTime(2022, 5, 9)), // Day 9
];
```